# Feasibility/value of caching with AppEngine backends?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, memcached

I've just finished watching the Google IO 2011 presentation on AppEngine backends (http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/app-engine-backends.html) which piqued my curiosity about using a backend instance for somewhat more reliable and configurable in-memory caching. It could be an interesting option as a third layer of cache, under in-app caching and memcache, or perhaps as a substitute for some cases where higher reliability is desirable.

Can anyone share any experience with this? Googling around doesn't reveal much experimentation here. Does the latency of a URLfetch to retrieve a value from a backend's in-memory dictionary render it less attractive, or is it not much worse than a memcache RPC?

I am thinking of whipping up some tests to see for myself, but if I can build on the shoulder of giants...thanks for any help :)

Comment: The obvious question here is why? It's not going to be faster (but probably not much slower, either), it'll have lower capacity, and it'll be more expensive.

Comment: All of what you say is true, but the upside, I guess, is that a Backend may be a little more reliable than Memcache - per Google's own presentation. As long as your backend doesn't go down your in-memory data should always be there and if it shuts down gracefully you get an opportunity to persist data to datastore. In memcache, data is evicted without any warning so there's no chance to persist it. The only way you can lose in-memory data is if it goes down unannounced...with memcache there's more possible loss scenarios. Correction from a Google-r would be welcome if I am wrong though!

Comment: I should say, though, that I am leaning toward starting with two layers of cache, in-app caching with global variables and then memcache, and seeing how that works out first before looking at a backend. Something like elasticache for AppEngine - where we can use more memcache if needed - would be nice by the way :)

Comment: Well, yes, memcache is indeed a cache. Your backend won't provide reliable storage unless you flush to the datastore, so it depends what sort of semantics you need. I'm hard pressed thinking of a scenario where you need storage that's more reliable than memcache, but can still roll-back unexpectedly if the backend gets terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: I was indeed considering a flush to datastore - a semantic that I'd love in memcache would be a 'persist upon eviction' process, but I know it's not necessarily in line with the performance goals of memcache. With polite shutdowns on a backend you at least get that option to persist. You're right though, nothing to stop data disappearing with a hard shutdown, but I figured that that might be less likely than unceremonious eviction from memcache :) Perhaps I'm not giving memcache enough credit relative to a backend though. Thanks for your comments Nick!

Comment: You're right that it's less likely, but my point is that there's not many scenarios in which occasional data loss is acceptable. Generally you either need a cache, in which case you don't mind stuff going away, or you need persistent storage, where data going away is a Very Bad Thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latency between a backend and frontend instance is extremely low.

If you think about it, all App Engine RPC's are fulfilled with "backend instances". The backends for the Datastore and Memcache are just run by Google for your convenience.

Most requests, according to the App Engine team, stay within the same datacenter - meaning latency is inter-rack and much lower than outside URLFetches.

A simple request handler and thin API layer for coordinating the in memory storage is all you need - in projects where I've set up backend caching, it's done a good job of fulfilling the need for more flexible in-memory storage - centralizing things definitely helps. The load balancing doesn't hurt either ;)

Comment: So you see similar latency for a backend memory fetch vs memcache? Slightly out of scope, but how do you manage queries where you can't look up something directly by key? I've been thinking that any queries I do I should do by key only, then look up entities in memory or in cache using those keys, and if any are missing, fetch them from the datastore. Is that a sound strategy? I suppose I should really just experiment myself with this...but wondering how or if others do this, or if they just use caching for direct single entity lookups by key.

Comment: URLFetch is an API call; API calls are not URLFetches.

Comment: @PeterJK : did you ever do this key-only query experiment?

Comment: @NickJohnson - you are correct, that's a misleading oversimplification. Edited for clarity.